# convert string in GMT format to datetime format

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting value error while converting,

```
from datetime import datetime
b="Sep 23 09:53:38 2019 GMT"
date = datetime.strptime(b, "%d %b %Y")
print(date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to completely decompose your time string to get a datetime:

```
date = datetime.strptime(b, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z")
```

> datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 23, 9, 53, 38)